# Get the date modified to be formatted with AM/PM with powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, formatting

I've currently got

```
Get-Item "C:\path\to\file.txt" | ForEach-Object { $_.LastWriteTime }
```

Which outputs like this

```
12/18/2018 16:54:32
```

But I want it to output like this

```
12/18/2018 4:54 PM
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: As an aside: the output you're getting looks like the `[datetime]` instance has been _stringified_ with `"$($_.LastWriteTime)"`; when output directly, you'd see something like `Thursday, July 7, 2022 3:44:57 PM` in the en-US (US-English) culture.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the DateTime objects formatting. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

```bash
Get-Item "C:\path\to\file.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
  $_.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")
}
```

Comment: Note that `hh` will return `04` for the hour even though it is the 4 PM hour, rather than the 4 AM hour. Use one `h` to return the time without a leading zero (it will still do 10, 11, 12 for those hours).

Comment: Nicely done; another thing worth noting: to get the format as shown in the question, `:ss` should be removed (no seconds).

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler to just use `(Get-Date -Format 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt')`

Comment: The question was not in how to get current datetime!

Comment: @OlehTarasenko It still answers the question, which is how to show 12-hour time with AM/PM.

Comment: @TylerH, it answers a _different question than asked without saying so_, which is likely to cause confusion, and with the exception of the (unmentioned) variation in the hour format (`hh` vs `h`), it
is in essence the same solution as the accepted one. Sure, this is simpler, _if you're solving a different, simpler problem_.
Speaking of simpler: `Get-Date -Format g` / `$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('g')` (with `en-US` as the current culture).

Comment: @mklement0 You say 'simpler', I say 'less readable' :-) I've clarified the answer by adding some context to make it clear it's more an answer reply to the accepted answer. Don't be led astray by the `Get-Date` value at the start; it's still answering the same question, just partially via a piggyback.

Comment: @TylerH, your edit perpetuates the confusing disconnect between the two uses cases. If you want to make the two approaches comparable, compare the accepted solution to `Get-Date $_.LastWriteTime -Format 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt'`, not to formatting the _current_ date.

Comment: P.S, @TylerH: If you make the solutions comparable, "much simpler" doesn't apply anymore, arguably the opposite does (depending on whether you favor native PowerShell vs. .NET API solutions).

Comment: @TylerH, in the absence of feedback, I've reverted your edit, because I think it only adds to the confusion.

Comment: I won't get into a rollback war over it if it doesn't make sense to you, but I fixed the revision though to use the correct code-formatted one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Convert 24hr time to 12hr with AM/PM ie, Monday 01/03/22 12:01 PM

Get-Date -Format "HH" -OutVariable time >$2
if ($time -ge 12) {
    $ptime = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yy hh:mm"
    Write-Host "Right now it is $ptime PM" 
} else {
    $atime = Get-Date -Format "dddd MM/dd/yy hh:mm"
    Write-Host "Right now it is $atime AM" 
}


#  clear variables

$time=$null
$atime=$null
$ptime=$null
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

Assuming that your current culture is US-English (in which case `$PSCulture` returns `en-US`), you have the following options to get the desired string format for a given [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date) instance, such as contained in `$_.LastWriteTime` in your command (`$PROFILE` is used as a sample input file):

```bash
# Use .ToString() with the general date-time format, "g":
# -> e.g., "7/14/2022 3:44 PM"
Get-Item $PROFILE | ForEach-Object { 
  $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('g') 
}

# Alternative, via Get-Date -Format
Get-Item $PROFILE | ForEach-Object { 
  Get-Date -Date $_.LastWriteTime -Format g
}
```

Note that the above implies that the simplest way to get the *current* date and time in the desired format is to use:

```bash
# Get the *current* date and time in general format.
# -> e.g. "7/14/2022 12:47 PM"
Get-Date -Format g
```

If you need a [*custom* format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) that isn't covered by one of the [*standard* formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings), use [kpogue's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842101/45375).

Read on for **background information**, including how to ask for formats from a *different* culture, notably how to use the `en-US` culture for formatting even while a different culture is in effect.

---

**The command in your question would *not* produce the display format in your sample output** - instead, it would result in a more verbose, culture-specific representation as you would see for the current date with [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date), such as `Thursday, July 7, 2022 3:44:57 PM` in the US-English culture.

However, **you *would* get such output if you were to *stringify* the `[datetime]` value *via string interpolation* with `"$($_.LastWriteTime)"`**, in which case PowerShell invariably applies the **[*invariant* culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**, which is *based on* the US-English culture, but distinct from it, notably in that it guarantees culture-invariance and long-term stability - specifically, in this case it differs with respect to 12-hour vs. 24-hour clock representations, in that it **uses a 24-hour clock**.

**[kpogue's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842101/45375) shows you how to use *custom* formatting** to achieve the desired output format; however, given that **it seems like you're interested in the *standard* (general) *US-English* date-time format**, the following solution is simpler (using `$PROFILE` as a sample file name):

[Standard date-time format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) `g` produces the desired format:

```bash
# Assumes that the current culture is en-US
Get-Item $Profile | ForEach-Object {
  $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('g') 
}
```

Sample output:

```
7/7/2022 3:44:57 PM
```

If your current culture is *not* `en-US`, you can pass the culture to use for formatting *explicitly*, as the second argument:

```bash
# Works irrespective of what the current culture is.
Get-Item $Profile | ForEach-Object { 
  $_.LastWriteTime.ToString('g', [cultureinfo] 'en-US') 
}
```

This relies on the [`[datetime]::ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ToString) method having overloads that accept an [`[IFormatProvider]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IFormatProvider)  argument, which is an interface that  the [`[cultureinfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo) type implements, so that casting `'en-US'` (the US-English culture's identifier) to `[cultureinfo]` results in that culture's general date-time format.